# Is it possible to make screen readers stop reading at some point of the page?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, uiaccessibility, nvda

I am facing an issue of aria and accessibility aria labels.

That's my problem:

After opens a page, I need that the screen reader reads the title and then stop reading the rest of the page. 
I need that the screen reader stops there, and just continue reading after the user uses TABS to navigate.

does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screen reader user has complete control over how much information is read.  They might have their settings so that nothing is read when the page is loaded except maybe the page title.  Or they might have it set so the entire page is read.  It's not something you can control, nor should you.  It's very user specific.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the already existing answer:

Of course you could force something like this using aria notifiy (aka on page load aria notify page title, and that's it). this would lead to the screenreader getting interrupted, the page title getting announced and then silence until the user moves (or other notification arrives). But this kind of behaviour would be super confusing to blind people, as it is pretty unnatural.

I myself am blind and believe me: Blind people, especially NVDA or Jaws users (don't know about Window Eyes) have an entire scripting language at the ready if need be. They may choose to make your web page appear completely different for them than it appears for others, react in different ways - and how verbose the page is presented (on braille display and voice) is entirely up to the blind user. Don't bother with that, they'll figure it out themselves

If the talking of the screenreader annoys them, they can always press shift to pause the screenreader or control to silence it altogether. They'll be fine.